Component Compatibility: CustomDockingRegion not available for 'xros 1.0', please update 'platforms' array in Package.swift
I have update vision pro simulator to 2.0 and xcode to 16, I'm still seeing this message when I try to add audio or videoDockingRegion to the Reality Composer Pro and build, is there anything I miss in the setup of the project?
I tried changing the minimum deployment target to visionOS 2.0 but didn't work
To reproduce:

open a visionOS project

open Reality Composer Pro 2.0 from tool kit

create a new scene from project browser

in the left navigator list, click add environment - then add video dock

build project, and I got the error above


